# Cassandra Drive Installation Failed in Python 3 on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, anaconda

I am creating a development environment with Python to work with cassandra, but I am not able to install Cassandra Driver when I try to install it with the command in `Windows 8.1` Power Shell. `"\ PIP INSTALL CASSANDRA-DRIVER"` and I have the following message error:

> Running setup.py install for cassandra-driver ... error
>   
> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py", lin
>   e 73, in console_to_str
>       return s.decode(sys.**stdout**.encoding)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 21
>   5, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
>   ne 342, in run
>       prefix=options.prefix_path,
>     File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 78
>   4, in install
>       **kwargs
>     File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
>   e 878, in install
>       spinner=spinner,
>     File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line
>    676, in call_subprocess
>       line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
>     File "c:\users\rodrigoaugusto\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py", lin
>   e 75, in console_to_str
>       return s.decode('utf_8')
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

Could someone help me ?, my current scenario and the following, Operating System: `Windows 8.1` `Python 3.6` and I am using `ANACONDA` / `Jupyter` `Notebook` to develop.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to pip, but not cassandra. Please refer to [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4825) for more details. You can also find a few workaround as well. My recommendation is to use python 2 as it's more stable (unless there is specific requirement for python3)